# QBO - Error while quering TaxRate with QB V3 API

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

I get an error while querying TaxeRate from QBO using QB API V3.

Here is my request:

```
        String query = "Select * FROM TaxRate ";
        List<? extends IEntity> result = service.executeQuery(query).getEntities();
```

below is what i get in return

```
Some other Exception in SDK or network happened: org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of com.intuit.ipp.data.SpecialTaxTypeEnum from String value 'NO_TAX': value not one of declared Enum instance names
 at [Source: N/A; line: -1, column: -1] (through reference chain: com.intuit.ipp.data.TaxRate["SpecialTaxType"])
```

Can someone help me?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is a server side change (Addition of a new Enum value) which is causing this devkit break. A newer version of devkit with latest changes (XSD) will be released soon. That will resolve the issue.

As a temporary workaround, you can try to call this without using devkit. Sample V3 call (using dev-defined) - https://gist.github.com/IntuitDeveloperRelations/0913b4c224de758fde0a

### Update

This change might get rollbacked from the server side soon. In that case, current devkit will work as it is.